# createReadStream directly from url

Tags: node.js, shopify

How can i read a file from `https://storage.googleapis.com` without download ?

```
let url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/shopify-tiers-assets-prod-us-east1/c84niyyf31t4bxhj7ulb2prf2r9p?GoogleAccessId=assets-us-prod%40shopify-tiers.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1611140532&Signature=bEiC5Ftxr8rCtiIfm3hyKKP%2B4EUf4TzPUAM3NPuO1jh7DkG1lr7DVQTMYd1rwC4DLMJAZfcQwca7X2Ab%2FWKNwbpfw%2FEjAIh%2B5qhsy77%2FP3BZFrAJjcpSHU6Mj2d3elv1cqTnVErPbig0TvB3caZ1P1apAVMXQP5WRHYGPcnXhV8g9%2B%2FRvQaO4myDS7qfhA89IicVI5e2pPwEMtUgeE6XQavY8ZdpzwLsO0XeAxsLBcH%2FezjIHPOShlRWN09OoqGwBWYcHOvULzA4Rt1fgtiejNI2vZo3FE806YWGW%2BbH%2BXzvFuNq7xMEDgvPIgkM9RPUNmcWSEzTo%2BHXAJ2Ph7%2FADw%3D%3D&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B+filename%3D%22bulk-102030409886.jsonl%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27bulk-102030409886.jsonl&response-content-type=application%2Fjsonl"

async function processLineByLine(url) {
  try {
    const rl = createInterface({
      input: createReadStream(url),
      crlfDelay: Infinity
    });

    rl.on("line", (line) => {
      console.log(line);
    });

    await once(rl, "close");

    console.log("File processed.");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could stream the file using `got` and then use `ndjson` as the file is json in each line.

```
const ndjson = require('ndjson')
const etl = require("etl");
const got = require("got");

const url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/shopify-tiers-assets-prod-us-east1/c84niyyf31t4bxhj7ulb2prf2r9p?GoogleAccessId=assets-us-prod%40shopify-tiers.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1611140532&Signature=bEiC5Ftxr8rCtiIfm3hyKKP%2B4EUf4TzPUAM3NPuO1jh7DkG1lr7DVQTMYd1rwC4DLMJAZfcQwca7X2Ab%2FWKNwbpfw%2FEjAIh%2B5qhsy77%2FP3BZFrAJjcpSHU6Mj2d3elv1cqTnVErPbig0TvB3caZ1P1apAVMXQP5WRHYGPcnXhV8g9%2B%2FRvQaO4myDS7qfhA89IicVI5e2pPwEMtUgeE6XQavY8ZdpzwLsO0XeAxsLBcH%2FezjIHPOShlRWN09OoqGwBWYcHOvULzA4Rt1fgtiejNI2vZo3FE806YWGW%2BbH%2BXzvFuNq7xMEDgvPIgkM9RPUNmcWSEzTo%2BHXAJ2Ph7%2FADw%3D%3D&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B+filename%3D%22bulk-102030409886.jsonl%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27bulk-102030409886.jsonl&response-content-type=application%2Fjsonl"

function getStream() {
  return got.stream(url);
}

getStream()
  .pipe(ndjson.parse())
  .pipe(etl.map(data => {
    // do something with data
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  }))
  .promise()
  .then(() => console.log("done"))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```